# How should I approach installing new toilet on concrete floor with cracked terracotta pipes?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I removed an old nonfunctional "Pittsburgh Toilet" from my basement and have a new one I would like to install.  Unfortunately, when I removed the old toilet, I came to find that there was no flange and the pipes were in horrible condition.

The original toilet seemed to be leveled with cement that I was able to chisel away to create a somewhat even surface.  It is not even enough to install a new toilet though.

My thoughts are to buy a 4" flange (https://www.lowes.com/pd/Oatey-PVC-Closet-Flange-4-in-Sold-Each/1002470748) and see if it fits inside far enough to bypass the cracked pipes and use thinset to level the flange and toilet surface.

I'd like to hear some other approaches (without removing floor) before I get started because I don't like mine.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Those flange extenders work well when you have good pipe but your pipe is shattered. Be prepared to have to chop out some of the floor until you get to good, solid pipe and then worry about what type of fittings/flanges you'll need.

Comment: Wow that’s in bad shape if my place I would be replacing the pipe especially if on a well.

Comment: I’m beginning to lean towards sealing it off